# which artificial neural network algorithms are most suitable for ranking problems?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I am having 5 student marks with 5 subjects each. I want to rank them **(1 to 5)** using artificial neural network algorithms. Suggest me the most appropriate artificial neural network algorithms for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have them each pick a different algorithm and research. If they are presenting their findings, then the class can see the differences between the algorithms.